# msbuild importing and overriding files

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, inheritance, msbuild

I've got a two projects and a solution file:

```
c:\dev\base\proja\proja.vbproj
c:\dev\base\proja\myfile1.aspx
c:\dev\base\proja\myfile1.aspx.vb
c:\dev\base\proja\myfile1.aspx.vb.designer
c:\dev\base\proja\myfile2.aspx
c:\dev\base\proja\myfile2.aspx.vb
c:\dev\base\proja\myfile2.aspx.vb.designer
```

and

```
c:\dev\base\projb\mysln.sln
c:\dev\base\projb\projb.vbproj
c:\dev\base\projb\myfile2.aspx
c:\dev\base\projb\myfile2.aspx.vb
c:\dev\base\projb\myfile2.aspx.vb.designer
```

`proja.vbproj` is the base project, while `projb.vbproj` is intended to import `proja.vbproj` and override the `myfile2.aspx etc` files.

`proja.vbproj` looks like this:

```
[...]
<Compile Include="myfile1.aspx.vb">
  <SubType>ASPXCodebehind</SubType>
  <DependentUpon>myfile1.aspx</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="myfile2.aspx.vb">
  <SubType>ASPXCodebehind</SubType>
  <DependentUpon>myfile2.aspx</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
[...]
<Content Include="myfile1.aspx" />
<Content Include="myfile2.aspx" />
[...]
```

while `projb.vbproj` looks like this:

```
[...]
<Import Project="$(ProjectDir)..\proja\proja.vbproj" />
[...]
<Compile Include="myfile2.aspx.vb">
  <SubType>ASPXCodebehind</SubType>
  <DependentUpon>myfile2.aspx</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
[...]
<Content Include="myfile2.aspx" />
[...]
```

`projb.vbproj` is a designed to just override the customised files of `proja.vbproj` - providing a single normalised location from which to maintain the project, while allowing specific overrides for per-site customizations.

The problem arises when I load `projb.vbproj` in Visual Studio 2013 and try and build it. It throws a tonne of errors because it cannot resolve the location of the of `myfile1.aspx` and associated files located in `proja.vbproj`. This appears to be because the imported paths are relative to the `projb.vbproj` location rather than `proja.vbproj` files location.

I've tried pre-appending `$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)` to all the files in `proja.vbproj` - but this doesn't resolve the issue as I believe `$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)` is contextually set based on the project that is being opened rather than imported.

I don't want to copy the entire `myproja.vbproj` files contents into `myprojb.vbproj` just to override one file - this seems messy and against the seemingly inheritance-centric methodology of msbuild, but perhaps I'm wrong here...

Is there any way to accomplish what I'm after? That is; override certain file locations of one project with file locations of another without having to duplicate the entire project file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a good thing you're trying to reuse parts of your project but the way you are doing it has a couple of disadvantages (and they are only going to get bigger if your project grows):

- as you noticed it doesn't work properly
- you could probably fix this by using `$(MsBuildThisFileDirectory)`, but that would mean whenever you Visual Studio to add files to your project, you'd have to apply the fix again
- project b directly depends on pretty much everything in project a, such tight coupling is never a good sign
- if MsBuild sees `Compile Include=aaa` it *adds* aaa to the compile list. Even if it's there already. So you're not overriding anything here, you're just adding to the files included in project a. Not sure if that is what you want?

What you can do instead:

- if projects need the same build settings (for compiler/linker/...), add those settings to a common, seperate file and include that in both projects
- if projects need common functionality, put just that functionality in a project and reference that project in the other projects. So instead of trying to override things with your build system, which is messy, provide a common base and then add classes to it. (I don't know anything at all about aspx/bb.net but surely it has a way to create 'library' type projects that you can reference in others?)
- in response to your comment: if only a couple of files are different, you can also use one single project with multiple build configurations. Each build configuration then enables different files. So normally you have configurations like Debug and Release, now you rename those and extra configurations like ReleaseCustom1/ReleaseCustom2.

For example:

```
 <!-- 500+ Common Files -->
 <Compile Include="myfile1.aspx.vb"/>
 <Compile Include="myfile2.aspx.vb"/>
 <!-- Some Specific Files -->
 <Compile Include="customfile1.aspx" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='ReleaseCustom1'"/>
 <Compile Include="customfile2.aspx" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='ReleaseCustom2'"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I actually tried `$(MsBuildThisFileDirectory)` and Visual Studio 2013 still doesn't play nice when it imports the project. If I have files in one project that I want for another project (the differences between  my projects are typically one or two files for a 500 file 'base' project) - should I create distinct projects that import the correct files rather than attempting inheritance (which doesn't seem to work)? What's the best practice?

Comment: 'Best practice' highly depends on the situation, but see my edit: maybe the last item is suitable for you.